E2E Competition Tests Forbidden 403 Error
So basically i am trying to implement some integration tests for competition, task, subtask creation and deletion, etc (e2e tests), but i keep being given Error 403 Forbidden. I will also attach what i get after running npm run. Previously I got an error regarding permissions so I modified beforeAll and this seems to fix it but now I get this.
import { HttpStatus, INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { Test, TestingModule } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { CompetitionController } from '../src/competition/competition.controller';
import { CompetitionService } from '../src/competition/competition.service';
import { SubmissionService } from '../src/competition/submission.service';
import { AuthService } from '../src/auth/auth.service';
import { Reflector } from '@nestjs/core';
import { getRepositoryToken } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import RoleEntity from '../src/auth/entity/role.entity';
import PermissionEntity from '../src/auth/entity/permission.entity';

describe('CompetitionController (e2e)', () => {
  let app;
  let requestAgent: request.SuperTest<request.Test>;

  const mockAuthService = {
    validateUser: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      id: 1,
      username: 'testuser',
      roles: ['admin'],
      permissions: [
        { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'create' },
        { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'delete' },
        { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'create' },
        { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'delete' },
      ],
    }),
    login: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
      access_token: 'valid-token',
    }),
  };

  const mockCompetitionService = {};

  const mockSubmissionService = {};

  beforeAll(async () => {
    const moduleFixture: TestingModule = await Test.createTestingModule({
      controllers: [CompetitionController],
      providers: [
        {
          provide: CompetitionService,
          useValue: mockCompetitionService,
        },
        {
          provide: SubmissionService,
          useValue: mockSubmissionService,
        },
        {
          provide: AuthService,
          useValue: mockAuthService,
        },
        Reflector,
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(RoleEntity),
          useValue: {
            save: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue({
              name: 'admin',
              permissions: [
                { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'create' },
                { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'delete' },
                { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'create' },
                { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'delete' },
              ],
            }),
          },
        },
        {
          provide: getRepositoryToken(PermissionEntity),
          useValue: {
            save: jest.fn(),
            findOne: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue(null),
          },
        },
      ],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleFixture.createNestApplication();
    await app.init();
    requestAgent = request(app.getHttpServer()) as unknown as request.SuperTest<request.Test>;

    const roleRepository = moduleFixture.get(getRepositoryToken(RoleEntity));
    const permissionRepository = moduleFixture.get(getRepositoryToken(PermissionEntity));

    const existingRole = await roleRepository.findOne({ where: { name: 'admin' } });
    if (!existingRole) {
      await roleRepository.save({
        name: 'admin',
        permissions: [
          { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'create' },
          { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'delete' },
          { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'create' },
          { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'delete' },
        ],
      });
    }

    const existingPermission = await permissionRepository.findOne({
      where: { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'create' },
    });

    if (!existingPermission) {
      await permissionRepository.save([
        { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'create', resourceRelationship: 'admin' },
        { resourceType: 'competition', accessOperation: 'delete', resourceRelationship: 'admin' },
        { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'create', resourceRelationship: 'admin' },
        { resourceType: 'task', accessOperation: 'delete', resourceRelationship: 'admin' },
      ]);
    }
  });

  afterAll(async () => {
    if (app) {
      await app.close();
    }
  });

  it('/comp (PUT) - Create Competition', async () => {
    const competitionDTO = {};

    await requestAgent
      .put('/comp')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .send(competitionDTO)
      .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });

  it('/comp/:slug/available (GET) - Check Slug Availability', async () => {
    await requestAgent
      .get('/comp/test-slug/available')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });

  it('/comp/:slug/task (PUT) - Create Task', async () => {
    const taskDTO = {};

    await requestAgent
      .put('/comp/test-slug/task')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .send(taskDTO)
      .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });

  it('/comp/:slug (DELETE) - Delete Competition', async () => {
    await requestAgent
      .delete('/comp/test-slug')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });

  it('/comp/:slug/task/:taskID (DELETE) - Delete Task', async () => {
    await requestAgent
      .delete('/comp/test-slug/task/12345')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });

  it('/comp/:slug/task/:taskID/submit (POST) - Submit Task', async () => {
    const submissionDTO = {};

    await requestAgent
      .post('/comp/test-slug/task/12345/submit')
      .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      .send(submissionDTO)
      .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
      .expect((res) => {
        expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      });
  });
});

Also this is what I get after running
● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp (PUT) - Create Competition
 
    expected 201 "Created", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      127 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      128 |       .send(competitionDTO)
    > 129 |       .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED)
          |        ^
      130 |       .expect((res) => {
      131 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      132 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:129:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
  ● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp/:slug/available (GET) - Check Slug Availability
 
    expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      137 |       .get('/comp/test-slug/available')
      138 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
    > 139 |       .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
          |        ^
      140 |       .expect((res) => {
      141 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      142 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:139:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
  ● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp/:slug/task (PUT) - Create Task
 
    expected 201 "Created", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      150 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      151 |       .send(taskDTO)
    > 152 |       .expect(HttpStatus.CREATED)
          |        ^
      153 |       .expect((res) => {
      154 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      155 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:152:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
  ● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp/:slug (DELETE) - Delete Competition
 
    expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      160 |       .delete('/comp/test-slug')
      161 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
    > 162 |       .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
          |        ^
      163 |       .expect((res) => {
      164 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      165 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:162:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
  ● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp/:slug/task/:taskID (DELETE) - Delete Task
 
    expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      170 |       .delete('/comp/test-slug/task/12345')
      171 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
    > 172 |       .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
          |        ^
      173 |       .expect((res) => {
      174 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      175 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:172:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
  ● CompetitionController (e2e) › /comp/:slug/task/:taskID/submit (POST) - Submit Task
 
    expected 200 "OK", got 403 "Forbidden"
 
      183 |       .set('Authorization', 'Bearer valid-token')
      184 |       .send(submissionDTO)
    > 185 |       .expect(HttpStatus.OK)
          |        ^
      186 |       .expect((res) => {
      187 |         expect(res.body).toEqual(true);
      188 |       });
 
      at Object.<anonymous> (competition.e2e-spec.ts:185:8)
      ----
      at Test._assertStatus (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:252:14)
      at ../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:308:13
      at Test._assertFunction (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:285:13)
      at Test.assert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:164:23)
      at Server.localAssert (../../../node_modules/supertest/lib/test.js:120:14)
 
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:54 PM   ERROR [Testing] Role name unavailable
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:54 PM   ERROR [Testing] SqliteError: UNIQUE constraint failed: permissions.resourceType, permissions.accessOperation, permissions.resourceRelationship
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:55 PM   ERROR [Testing] Unable to assign permission to role
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:55 PM   ERROR [Testing] Unable to assign permission to role
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:55 PM   ERROR [Testing] Could not find any entity of type "RoleEntity" matching: {
    "relations": {
        "permissions": true
    },
    "where": {
        "name": "New Role"
    }
}
[Nest] 55230  - 11/14/2024, 6:14:55 PM   ERROR [Testing] Unable to assign permission to role

